# Draw in pygame with inverted Y axis

Tags: python, pygame

I am writing a scientific simulation in Python and I'm working with pygame to show the evolution of a system.

I would like to draw the evolution with common axis, like in mathematics (origin at bottom left part of screen and positive axis increasing up and right). I know and understand that axis are treated in Pygame as the standard 2d graphics.

Is there any builtin pygame function for this? or I just should pre-process my data to show them in the coordinate system that I want?  Or even more, Is pygame the right choice for this?

Update: I tried with `pygame.transform.flip()` but it rotates all the given Surface (of course). As I am blitting multiple surfaces to screen, I end with the whole information flipped (I am drawing numbers and letters so they appear upside down). I will try with matplotlib soon for a quick, simple and painless solution

Comment: PyGame is not arbitrarily enforcing this.  At the lowest level the origin of your screen is the upper left.  PyGame is a high level abstraction over SDL which is yet another abstraction over OpenGL / software rendering written in C.  It is not uncommon to have to translate your units to compensate for this, but it is not as hard as one would think.

Comment: Yes, Talking about points in a 2D space, simple math can invert the data easily, and I understand that this is almost done by everybody. My question goes in the direction of supporting this requirement in the framework.

Comment: Have you looked at pygame.transform.flip?

Comment: @Anna I tried with but the screen didn't update as expected. I tried with the screen main surface. The screen seems to be overwritten and I get just an empty screen.

Comment: I managed to make it work with transform.flip but I have text in screen that is flipped too and becomes unreadable. Separating these tasks (drawing things by separate) is, i think, harder than transform raw numeric data to a user-defined axis.